# Strange behavior on android widget SearchView

Tags: android, searchview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

My layout hierarchy is like:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
   <AppBarLayout>
      <CollapsingToolbar Layout/>
        <SearchView/>
      </CollapsingToolbar Layout/>   
      <Toolbar/>
   </AppBarLayout>
   <ViewPager/>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

The beahavior is like when I come to this page I populate ViewPager data.But then if user just click searchView along with keyboard opens up viewpager data populated is invoked . Same happens when we click back on keyboard, thus making a fast reload action. Can anyone help me on this case

For more info:
layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:collapsedTitleGravity="center"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/color_white"
            app:statusBarScrim="@android:color/transparent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:background="@color/color_transparent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" >
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:queryHint="text_hello"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <TextView android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:textColor="@color/color_dark_green"
            android:text="Saly"/>

    <FrameLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/search_results_tab_container"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

in activity that framelayout am replacing with a custom TabLayout and View Pager and on start up populating the datas.

When I run the app datas get populated by calling getView method.Later when I click on searchView widget along with keyboard opens, getView() method is also called.
Same happens on keyboard close back button action.Am stuck here. Can anyone point out the problem

Comment: Can you provide some more details / maybe source code for the logic you are describing?

Comment: Actually no logic I have done. But one more thing is like when I used EditText over SearchView in same layout everything worked fine